# UIImageView on top and set size

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

1) I have a `UIView` with a `UIImageView` on it, i load pictures from the image gallery. I want to know how I would "center" the picture on the screen and make that the aspect ratio isn't changed. For instance if I load a picture that is on landscape mode, how do I make sure that the picture isn't stretched all over the screen? My app is working in portrait mode.

2) In that same view I want to add the effect that when the user touches the screen the botton menu fades out and back in when he presses again. I'm not sure what that is called and I couldn't get the `tap gesture recognizer` to work.

EDIT:

I set the `UIImageView` on page load

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
xlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.setLablePosition];
xlabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

imgView.image = self.appDelegate.theImg; // now the image is put on a UIImageView that is "full screen"
xlabel.text = @"Some text";
[imgView addSubview:xlabel];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

and as for `Tap gesture` :

```
-(IBAction)screenTapped{
NSLog(@"screen Tapped");
}
```

the `IBAction` is linked to the `tap gesture recognizer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was

1) add `imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

2) like Omar Abdelhafith said i added `imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`, the `UITapGestureRecognizer` for me was created it the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

For centering the UIImageView in the view you would do the following

```
//First give imgView the correct size
//You may need to divide the size by some constant if the image is too big
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.appDelegate.theImg.size.width, self.appDelegate.theImg.size.width);
//Then center it
imgView.center = self.view.center;
```

For adding the tap gesture recognizer do the following

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenTapped)];
//By deafualt interaction is disabled
imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imgView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Comment: Welcome any time :) also please dont forget to accept the answer if this was helpful :)

Comment: "2)" was helpful, that the problem with 2 art questions ^_^